# How to debug the software reset in the ECU?

Tags: debugging, microcontroller, autosar, trace32, lauterbach

I would like to understand how to debug and find the root cause of a software reset or a Vector Catch reset. Suppose I am using the AUTOSAR framework, and when I flash the code, I am experiencing continuous resets. I want to know what the possible ways are to debug the software reset in the ECU. Some of the ways i found like `stack trace`, `logs prin`t etc.. . Is there any other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run the code for at least some of the instructions sets I will recomand first to have a look at the reset flags of status registers. Depends on the microcontroller you can get useful information for the beggining in order to isolate your reset cause and understand from which module/zone is comming the reset/vector catch. The search area for such things is quite large and there can be problems on the order of read/write RAM, incorrect PORT initialization, etc. It will be helpfull if you can briefly describe what are you up to do in the software and we can give you a more precise answere in terms of investigation.